# Heroku: RubyGem version error: rails(2.3.15 not = 2.3.14)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Of course you all heard about the latest security hole in Rails which requires some updates. I'm currently using version 2.3.14 of Rails and therefore tried updating to 2.3.15 (the patched version).

On my local machine the process really went *the rails way*. But after pushing the changes to Heroku and waiting for deployment, my app didn't start. It says in the logs

```
RubyGem version error: rails(2.3.15 not = 2.3.14)
```

No how could that happen? My `Gemfile` says

```
gem 'rails', '~> 2.3.15'
```

and my `Gemfile.lock` says

```
GEM
  specs:
    rails (2.3.15)
```

and, finally, Heroku tells me

```
Installing rails (2.3.15)
```

Really, where is the problem? Other people having this problem?

### Solution

The answer by Charles included the solution, which is to update the `RAILS_GEM_VERSION` to `2.3.15` in `config/environment.rb`.

### Important Notice

If you have the same troubles, please use one of the [proposed solutions](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/rubyonrails-security/61bkgvnSGTQ) **immediatly**. There are already known cases of corrupted Rails apps!

Comment: My guess is that another gem is dependent on rails 2.3.14, so you'll have to update one or more of those before pushing up.  Of course, it seems like you'd be seeing this on your dev machine too.  Are you testing your Procfile with `foreman start` on your local machine before pushing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you also need to do change `RAILS_GEM_VERSION` to `3.2.15` in environment.rb:

If you find yourself having to do the whole upgrading process over again, you can follow these steps:

- Run your tests and make sure everything works
- Open up a new branch through git (`git checkout -b new_rails`)
- Change Rails 3.2.15 in your Gemfile
- Change RAILS_GEM_VERSION to '3.2.15' in environment.rb
- Run `bundle update rails`
- Run the tests and see if everything still works
- If not, reverse back to the old branch by doing `git checkout master`; optionally delete the new branch by doing `git branch -D new_rails`

Taken from this question:
[Site dead. "ACTION REQUIRED: Rails Security Vulnerability "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295007/site-dead-action-required-rails-security-vulnerability/14295186#14295186)